# Tridion Sites 9 and DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, sites-9

Does anybody knows what happens with Tridion Sites 9 and DXA 2.0? I think I have all the configuration files and settings ok, but I am not able to make it work.

Is there any known issues? Any workaround?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Someone got it to work: http://hem-kant.blogspot.com/2018/11/sdl-tridion-sites-9-with-dxa-20-on-windows10.html

Comment: The curious thing is that I don't get any error, but home screen is white

Answer (score 5):

DXA 2.1 .Net will support Tridion Sites 9 and is planned to be released in the coming days.

Comment: DXA.NET 2.1 has been released now. Unfortunately, for Java Web Applications, you will have to await DXA 2.2 to benefit from the new features. However, DXA Java 2.0 will run fine on Tridion Sites 9.0 / DXD 11.0.

Answer (score 3):

Quick Fix: SWitch off the Custom Resolver (the one that controls the link depth resolving).

It's not formally supported but will be in DXA 2.1 as far as I know.

There is another issue with the context services (explained in the blog post by Hem noted above).

### update - per Rick's comment below:

> There is more clarity on the reported issue with DXA Resolver UI Extension: it works fine with Sites 9 as long as you don't install it in the WebUI folder. The default location (configured in cms-import.ps1) works fine

Comment: The problem with the 9.0 Context Service is that it is more strict regarding URL encoding (because of a Tomcat upgrade) and hence not compatible wirh CIL 10.1. This is fixed in [CIL 11.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sdl.Web.Context.Client/) (which DXA 2.1 will use).

Comment: In the meantime, you can try to build DXA 2.0 against CIL 11.0 or configure `AdfContextClaimsProvider` instead of `ContextServiceClaimsProvider` (in `Unity.config`). This effectively disables Context Engine functionality, but at least you Web App will run.

Comment: As @RickPannekoek mentioned we need to disable the context service dependency to run DXA 2.0 with Tridion Sites 9, that's all I did in order to make DXA 2.0 works with Tridion 9

Comment: There is more clarity on the reported issue with DXA Resolver UI Extension: it works fine with Sites 9 as long as you *don't* install it in the `WebUI` folder. The default location (configured in `cms-import.ps1`) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

DXA 2.1 is out, but it's only compatible with Sites 9 (as far as Tridion is concerned). Compatibility overview [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-445ED96D-A503-4022-9CEA-160DA3658586)

Comment: The main reason for DXA 2.1 release was to leverage/showcase the new features in Tridion Sites 9.0 / DXD 11.0.  However, compatibility with SDL Web 8(.5) will be re-introduced in DXA 2.2 (together with Java Web App support).

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with SDL Tridion Sites 9.0 and MS SQL Server which causes an invalid page template being used for pages with page template inherited from parent. This may result in pages returning an internal server error or just missing header and footer.

This issue can be fixed by applying hotfix CM_9.0.0.13336.