# Is DXA-2.1 available with Java?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.1

I am looking for Java DXA-2.1 source on GitHub, checked on GitHub but not able to find 2.1.0 release on repository, please provide information on this?

I looked into repository: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DXA 2.1 is avaliable for .NET only, see [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-BEDE64AE-1E23-4784-AE5E-7DA84B26F1AA)

> The Java version is planned for release soon after 2.1 in the subsequent 2.2 release

Also, [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/19498/1169) (in the comment):

Answer (score 4):

**Important:**

The DXA 2.1 release provides updates only to the .NET version of DXA. The Java version is planned for release soon after 2.1 in the subsequent 2.2 release. Until the 2.2 release is available, all references to the Java version should be assumed to be unchanged and as provided in the prior release 2.0.

Refer to the [DXA 2.1 release notes](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-7000F999-9BCF-4EE3-9EB6-FE8510B469F2)

I hope it helps